# laravel BelongsTo relationship with different databases not working

Tags: laravel

I've seen in several places to "stay away" from this, but alas - this is how my DB is built:

```
class Album extends Eloquent {

   // default connection

   public function genre() {
       return $this->belongsTo('genre');
   }
```

and the Genre table:

```
class Genre extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = 'Resources';

}
```

My database.php:

```
'Resources' => array(
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => 'localhost',
                    'database'  => 'resources',
                    'username'  => 'user',
                    'password'  => 'password',
                    'charset'   => 'utf8',
                    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => '',
            ),

 'mysql' => array(
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => 'localhost',
                    'database'  => 'my_data',
                    'username'  => 'user',
                    'password'  => 'password',
                    'charset'   => 'utf8',
                    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => '',
            ),
```

and when I try to run

```
Album::whereHas('genre', function ($q) {
   $q->where('genre', 'German HopScotch'); 
});
```

it doesn't select properly (doesn't add the database name to the table "genres"):

```
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_data.genres' doesn't exist
```

Its important to note that this works perfectly:

```
Album::first()->genre;
```

*Update*

The best I've found so far is to use the builder's "from" method to specifically name the correct connection.
I've discovered that the builder inside the query can receive "from"

```
Album::whereHas('genre', function ($q) {
   $q->from('resources.genres')->where('genre', 'German HopScotch'); 
});
```

This is a decent solution but it requires me to dig in the database php and find a good way to get the proper table and database name from the relation 'genre'.

I will appreciate if anyone else can build on this solution and make it more general.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you having this issue in?

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2

Comment: i have answered similar problem on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659224/laravel-hasmany-across-multiple-connections/52755812#52755812 hope this would help

Comment: i have answered similar problem on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659224/laravel-hasmany-across-multiple-connections/52755812#52755812 hope this would help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my own solution and it works in general for me but its mega-complicated.

I'm using the builder "from" method to set the table and database correctly inside the subquery. I just need to pass the correct information inside.

Assume the subquery can be as complicated as "genres.sample" or even deeper (which means albums has a relation to genres, and genres has a relation to samples)
this is how

```
$subQuery = 'genres.samples';
$goDeep = (with (new Album));

$tableBreakdown =  preg_split('/\./', $subQuery); //  = ['genres', 'samples']

// I recurse to find the innermost table $album->genres()->getRelated()->sample()->getRelated()
foreach ($tableBreakdown as $table)
    $goDeep = $goDeep->$table()->getRelated();

// now I have the innermost, get table name and database name

$alternativeConnection =  Config::get("database.connections." . $goDeep->getConnectionName() . ".database"); // should be equal to the correct database name

$tableName = $goDeep->getTable(); // I have to use the table name in the "from" method below

Album::whereHas($subQuery, function ($q) use ($alternativeConnection, $tableName) {
$q->from("$alternativeConnection.$tableName"); 
$q->where(....... yadda yadda);
    });
```

tl:dr;

```
Album::whereHas('genres', function ($q) { 
    $q->from('resources.genres')->where(....); 
});
```

Answer (score 44):

Solution for laravel v5.7 and above

```
class Album extends Eloquent {

   // default connection

   public function genre() {
       return $this->setConnection('Resources')->belongsTo('genre');
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Be careful this solution works most of the time but it can create some side effects. if you're updating the model after getting the relation, you will have a SQL issue (doing the update on the wrong database connection).

Comment: I don't think you need setConnection at all for Laravel 5.7+. Just make sure you **specify the connection for both models**, otherwise when you try to access one model from the other it will default to the source model's connection if the destination model has no connection specified.

Comment: This isn't the correct way to do it since you permanently changes the connection of the model as soon as you use the relationship and therefore after you won't be able to save the model again.

Answer (score 16):

This is the way it worked for me:

In my .env and config/database.php i have defined my other connection => [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

I updated my model this way:

```
class MyOtherDBModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tablename';
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->table = env('DB_DATABASE_2').'.'.$this->table;
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}

class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function myOtherModel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MyOtherDBModel::class, 'field', 'field');
    }
}
```

Now i can call

```
$query = MyModel::whereHas('myOtherModel');
```

Comment: Amazing @Alex, it works like a charm  It's like using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: Best solution for me too. Thanks

Comment: Defining `protected $connection` in each Model is just enough.

Comment: @Turako you sure is working when you use belongsTo, whereHas, etc ? The time this post was written by just adding connection was not working.

Comment: @Alex No. It's not working in Laravel 8. it's a Laravel flaw, I think.

Comment: @Alex Don't forget to pass your $attributes to parent::__construct($attributes);

Comment: @stillatmylinux thanks, i updated the code 

Answer (score 7):

Add the connection variable with the default connection on the genre model:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
```

I had some problems with the relationships by not adding this.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) will do what you want to do

```
Album::with(['genre' => function ($q) {
   $q->connection('Resources')
     ->where('genre', 'German HopScotch'); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone reaches here.

When you are fetching data using a relationship from **different database connections**, make sure that your related table has the `$connection` property defined even if it's the **default connection**.

`Account` Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'different_connection';

    public function verifiedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'verified_by');
    }
}
```

`User` Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    // this one uses the default - `database.default` connection
    public function approved()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Account::class, 'verified_by');
    }
}
```

As soon as I do `Account:find($id)->verifiedBy`, it will throw error. Look at the **database** name and you'll find. But if you do, `User::find($id)->approved`, it will work fine, because the `Account` model has the connection defined. And not the vice-versa.

So, just to be safe, if you deal with **multiple database connections**, put the `$connection` property in the models.

Laravel's [implementation](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/9e11007458b30af7cd3043830502462953ef8122/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L748-L755)

Answer (score 5):

you should clone before otherwise you're changing the default connection of the model. it creates side effect.

```
class Album extends Eloquent {
    public function genre() {
        $newResource = clone $this;
        return $newResource->setConnection('Resources')->belongsTo('genre');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue on Laravel 5.6. On a **Many-to-Many** scenario, and supposing the connection from my `ModelA` was the default one, what I did was the following:

1.- Prefix the schema name in the relationships:

```
// From ModelA and default connection (a.k.a connection1)
$this->belongsToMany('ModelB', 'schema.pivot-table-name');

// From ModelB and connection2
$this->belongsToMany('ModelA', 'schema.pivot-table-name');
```

2.- Overwrite connection parameter within the `ModelB` class **and also** specify the schema as a prefix in the overwritten `$table` attribute e.g.

```
protected $connection = 'connection2';

protected $table = 'connection2-schema-name.table';
```

3.- In case of requiring a custom behavior for the pivot table, what I did was just to implement the required model and specify it via the `->using('PivotModel');` function on the models relationships (as stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)). Finally I did the same as in the point 2 above, but on the pivot model

I haven't tried it yet, but I guess the same can be done for other kind of relationships, at least for the basic ones (One-to-One, One-to-Many, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when relationship wasn't working off the model connection.

My solution was to override the belongsToMany method on the model trying to establish. See example below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class ConnectionModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Override method to allow inheriting connection of parent
     *
     * Define a many-to-many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string  $table
     * @param  string  $foreignKey
     * @param  string  $otherKey
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany|BelongsToMany
     */
    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
        // If no relationship name was passed, we will pull backtraces to get the
        // name of the calling function. We will use that function name as the
        // title of this relation since that is a great convention to apply.
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            $relation = $this->getBelongsToManyCaller();
        }

        // First, we'll need to determine the foreign key and "other key" for the
        // relationship. Once we have determined the keys we'll make the query
        // instances as well as the relationship instances we need for this.
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $instance = new $related;

        // get connection from parent
        $instance->setConnection(parent::getConnectionName());

        $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

        // If no table name was provided, we can guess it by concatenating the two
        // models using underscores in alphabetical order. The two model names
        // are transformed to snake case from their default CamelCase also.
        if (is_null($table)) {
            $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
        }

        // Now we're ready to create a new query builder for the related model and
        // the relationship instances for the relation. The relations will set
        // appropriate query constraint and entirely manages the hydrations.
        $query = $instance->newQuery();

        return new BelongsToMany($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1: This is my .env with two database connection

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=foreign_key_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=foreign_key_test_2
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=
```

2: in my config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
        'unix_socket' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

3: State model from other database

```
class State extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'foreign_key_test_2.states';
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

4: Country model from 1st database where i made my relation with other database table

```
class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $table = 'countries';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'state_id'
    ];


    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }
}
```

5: Final step is my route

```
Route::get('city', function(){
    return $country = Country::with('state')->get();
});
```

6: this is working fine for me. Let me know with your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good article for this here: http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

You basically have to specify your two connections in your config file like so:

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

So your two connections are aliased to `mysql` and `mysql2`.

Then you can tell eloquent which 'alias' to use like so:

```
<?php

class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

Then you can setup your relationships like normal.

**tl;dr:** Basically instead of specifying the table name as `$connection` in eloquent, specify the connection alias in your configuration and it should work.

Comment: this is exactly what I did, I think I was clear in my example that I use a model and set a connection. You are welcome to try exactly that, and see that using "whereHas" doesn't work properly as I've stated.

Comment: Can you show me your `database.php` configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to use the default connection.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as MainModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class BaseModel extends MainModel
{
    function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        // laravel bug
        // in belongsTo relationship, default connection not used
        $this->connection = Config::get('database.default');
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To start change 'Resources' in **database.php** by 'resources', will be better !

I'm curious, can you try that ?

```
Album::whereHas('genre', function ($q) {
   $q->setConnection('resources')->where('genre', 'German HopScotch'); 
});
```

Comment: :( Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setConnection()

Comment: @NiRR did you solved it..? I am also getting the same.