# Laravel HasMany across multiple connections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to retrieve `Offer`s related to `Offer` on a second table `offer_related` because I can't change the schema of the `Offer` table.

I have two databases on different connections, `offers` on one, and `offer_related` on another.

For the sake of argument, I'm going to name databases as follows for clarity in my examples with regards to which can change and which can't.

- database containing `offers` henceforth known as `immutable`
- database containing `offer_related` henceforth known as `mutable`

Example schema is as follows

```
connection1.mutable.offer_related

offer_id | related_offer_id
---------------------------
1        | 2
1        | 3

connection2.immutable.offers

id | name
---------------------------
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | baz
```

I'm assuming it'd be a belongsToMany relationship, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'immutable.offer', 'id');

// Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'offer'
```

I've also tried to manually build out a belongsToMany relationship with a custom query with no success.

I'd like to be able to call

```
Offer::find(1)->related; // Offer(2), Offer(3)
```

Comment: Can you try this and see if it works? `return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'mutable.offer_related', 'offer_id', 'related_offer_id');`

Comment: That works, great! Post an answer and I'll accept. Thanks very much.

Comment: Ok! I've done that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the relationship to:

```
    return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'mutable.offer_related', 
                                'offer_id', 'related_offer_id');
```

Your original query was trying to establish a relationship without using the relation table (offer_related). That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem too, then solved with a trait:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Traits\Model;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait HasCrossDatabaseRelation {

    public function getTable() {
        if (! isset($this->table)) {
            $this->table = str_replace(
                '\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this)))
            );
        }

        $configConnections = config('database.connections');

        $databaseName = $configConnections[$this->getConnectionName()]['database'];

        return $databaseName . "." . $this->table;
    }

}
```

then use that trait and set the $connection property on each models. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a trait:

```
trait HasCrossDbRelationships {

  /**
   * Define a one-to-many relationship with connection attribute
   *
   * @param  string  $connection
   * @param  string  $related
   * @param  string  $foreignKey
   * @param  string  $localKey
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
   */
  public function hasManyCrossDb($connection, $related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
  {
      $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);
      $instance->setConnection($connection);

      $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

      $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

      return $this->newHasMany(
          $instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey
      );
  }

}
```