# PHP "with" keyword - what does "with" do?

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone please explain what PHP "with" does?

**Example begins:**

Say I have a class:

`\App\fa_batch`

*What is the difference between this statement:*

```
$w = (with (new \App\fa_batch))
       // uses 'with'
       // returns App\fa_batch
```

*and this statement?*

```
$n = (new \App\fa_batch)
       // does not use 'with'
       // also returns App\fa_batch
```

**Context / Background Info:**

I'm having trouble finding documentation for `with`, maybe because the PHP.net, stack overflow and google search engines considers `php "with" keyword` such a common search phrase.

If context helps, I came across this usage of the word `with` from this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33222754/5722034

Comment: *"I'm having trouble finding documentation for `with`."* -- take it as a hint and try to guess.

Comment: @axiac Logically it would either mean I have entered in insufficient search phrase, or no documentation exists.  It also means I want to throw my computer out the window, but that's rather less logical.

Comment: @JaseLeow Indeed, `with` is a common English word and the search engines usually ignore it or assign it a low value. However, searching on http://php.net should bring you at some point to the language definition page where all the keywords are listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`with` is not a keyword, it's a [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) function. The extra space between `with` and `(` is a red herring.

The [5.2 docs include it in miscellaneous helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#miscellaneous). [The source is available on github as well](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cb48cf54fcd16a8cac246fcb98340cc2c9ed6b5a/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L1006)

Comment: its not asking for Laravel framework " With " Funtion .. its Talking about `$w = (with (new \App\fa_batch))` differents b/w `$n = (new \App\fa_batch)

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar, what you've just described there **is** the `with()` function call in the laravel framework.

Comment: Your related question seems to deal with the Eloquent eager loading, not the helper function.

Comment: i pasted some source below if people are interested. thanks.

Comment: @devon yes, I was researching about Eloquent, but I was thrown by the extra whitespace between the `with` and  `(`

Comment: @JaseLeow that comment was directed towards the original answer (before it was edited).  This `with` helper is not related to Eloquent, only Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#miscellaneous

with() is a helper function that just returns the object.

A normal use case I've seen is when you're cloning an object, it allows you to chain onto that clone:

```
$object = new Object();
with(clone $object)->doSomethingWithoutAffectingTheOriginal();
```

In the use case you've provided, there is no difference.  with() is completely redundant if you've wrapped the creation of the instance in parentheses.

Comment: thank you for explaining the use case here. helpful +1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answers by various posters, I've realised it is a function in Laravel. Here is the Laravel source:  Taken from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`

```
if (! function_exists('with')) {
    /**
     * Return the given object. Useful for chaining.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $object
     * @return mixed
     */
    function with($object)
    {
        return $object;
    }
}
```

From that terse comment there, I understand it is used for chaining, e.g. queries together.  (I use the term 'understand' loosely.)

Answer (score 1):

### tldr

The `with` function *has been* used to chain methods, but is no longer required. Since php 5.4 you can simply write `(new MyObject)->myMethod()` - this was not possible prior to v5.4:

Example: https://3v4l.org/57dc0#v5.3.29

### More detailed answer

The `with` was a workaround to use the instance without assigning it to a variable:

```
$instance = new A;
$instance->doSomething();
```

Using the `with` function (works prior to v5.4 - [example](https://3v4l.org/7ARNb#v5.3.29)):

```
with(new A)->doSomething();
```

Since v5.4 you can simply write:

```
(new A)->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

`with` **is not** a [PHP keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Also take a look at the [language reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) page.

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing really? What about the accepted answer? Should it be a comment too?