# Laravel whereRelation with another database connection

Tags: php, laravel

I am just using Laravel `whereRelation`. It runs smooth and as expected if the relations between 2 tables is in the same database (`DB_A`). The problem is when I have to use 2 databases (`DB_A` and `DB_B`). In the model relationship I put the connections and there is no problem

```
// Model user DB_A

protected $connection = 'mysql';

public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'id_user');
}
```

```
// Model address DB_B

protected $connection = 'mysql2';
protected $table = 'address';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user');
}
```

In the query I want to get all the relationship between those 2 tables. The query like:

```
$data = User::with('address')->reorder('id', 'desc');
$data = $data->whereRelation('address', 'status', '=', 'verified');
```

I got the error say that table `address` doesn't exist in `DB_A` which is belong to `DB_B`. If i remove the line whereRelation takeplace it doesn't give any errors. How to handle or specify the database name and table name in `whereRelation`?

EDIT: Both `DB_A` and `DB_B` is in different Host.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel BelongsTo relationship with different databases not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422593/laravel-belongsto-relationship-with-different-databases-not-working)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the second connection is on another machine. Both db is not in the same machine. I kept getting error the table doesn't exist, even when I set the table name or connection multiple times. Is it possible to make relation with multiple db with different server machine?

Comment: Do you mean different host ?

Comment: yaa different host

Answer (score 0):

**Try it will hopefully work**

*Model address DB_B*

```
 class User  extends Eloquent {
    
       // *******default connection************
    
       public function address() {
           return $this->setConnection('mysql')->belongsTo(Address::class, 'id_user');
       }
    }
```

*Model address DB_B*

```
class Address extends Eloquent {

   // *******default connection************

   public function user() {
       return $this->setConnection('mysql2')->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user');
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it before. Not giving any progress for now. And I updated my question. `DB_A` and `DB_B` is on different Host