# how to set connection for querying relationship existence

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

How can I set a connection for a relationship in Laravel, following the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence, where we can query if that relationship exists?

For example, imagine you want to retrieve all blog posts that have at least one comment but comment on different database

With multiple database connections :

```php
return [
    'default' => 'mysql-key1',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql-key1' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => 'key1_dbname,
            // etc
        ],
        'mysql-key2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => 'key2_dbname',
            // etc
        ]
    ]
];
```

Blog Post Model:

```php
class BlogPostModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'blogs_post';

    protected $connection = 'mysql-key1';
}
```

Comment model

```php
class CommentModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'comments';

    protected $connection = 'mysql-key2';
}
```

```php
// Retrieve all posts that have at least one comment...
$posts = Post::has('comments')->get();
```

So how to set connection for relationship 'comment'

Comment: you can retrieve data from only one database within one sql query

Comment: Model will automatically set connection for you relation which you have called. Is it not setting connection which you have given in you model?

Comment: @M-Khawar Yes model automatically set the connection for relation 'mysql-key1'. it should be ''mysql-key2"
So  query show error: `database_main.blog_post.comments` doesn't exist

Comment: @DenisSinyukov so basically this issue cannot be resolved?

Comment: @ShinSangKi you have to do the check manually by running a query to the second database. You cannot define a relation between multiple data sources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel BelongsTo relationship with different databases not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422593/laravel-belongsto-relationship-with-different-databases-not-working)

Comment: You can't do it with a single query

Comment: 1. get posts
2. get comments
3. Go through all posts and form an array of posts that contain comments.

Comment: *Leading question*: can you write a raw sql that will use 2 or more databases?  ORM can't either