# Laravel Nova BelongsToMany relation | models in two separate databases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-nova

- Laravel Version: 10.47.0
- Nova Version: 4.23.0 (Silver Surfer)
- PHP Version: 8.2.13
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 10.11.6-MariaDB-1:10.11.6+maria~deb11
- Operating System and Version: Debian 11
- Browser type and version: Chrome 122.0.6261.95
- Reproduction Repository: -

#### Description:

I have many to many relation where Products are stored in another database than Distribution. I tried few solutions but none seems working. I searched nova changelog to see if there was fixes for it and it seems that there were none. Nova keep search for distribution_product table in "corcel" connection. I want store distribution_product table in "mysql" connection.

I'm doing something wrong or it is a bug?

Distribution model:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
public function product(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('amount')->using(DistributionProduct::class);
    }
```

DistributionProduct model:

```
class DistributionProduct extends Pivot
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $table = 'distribution_product';
}
```

Product model:

```
class Product extends model
{

    protected $connection = 'corcel';

    public function distribution(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Distribution::class)->withPivot('amount')->using(DistributionProduct::class);
    }
}
```

#### Detailed steps to reproduce the issue on a fresh Nova installation:

```
php artisan make:model -m Distribution
php artisan make:model -m Product
php artisan make:model -m DistributionProduct --pivot
php artisan nova:resource Distribution
php artisan nova:resource Product
php artisan migrate

add corcel mysql connection to config/database.php

updade models like in description
```

Error:

```
 "message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'corcel_database.distribution_product' doesn't exist (Connection: corcel, SQL: select `posts`.*, `distribution_product`.`distribution_id` as `pivot_distribution_id`, `distribution_product`.`product_ID` as `pivot_product_ID`, `distribution_product`.`amount` as `pivot_amount` from `posts` inner join `distribution_product` on `posts`.`ID` = `distribution_product`.`product_ID` where `post_type` = product and `distribution_product`.`distribution_id` = 2)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
```

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422593/laravel-belongsto-relationship-with-different-databases-not-working

Comment: @kris-gjika nope, setConnection method not exist in belongsToMany, also it says to set $connection - I already did it

Comment: ahh I see the issue, eloquent being efficient loading products will join your pivot table and query the required distribution ids. Are these DBs on the same server? If not, this join is not possible and the relation from this side, `$distribution->load('products')` is not possible via normal relation queries.

Comment: Yes, databases are on same server.

Comment: did you try adding the database name into `$table` for the pivot model? like `protected $table = 'distribution_database.distribution_product';`