# Eloquent model to represent entity in 2 db

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

In our app we have an entity, as per app design we have, the entity resides in 2 dbs. Conditionally we need to switch the source DB. 
Further, though same entity the tables slightly differ in 2 databases. What would be the correct way to have eloquent models for this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple database in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gone through several sites, ***Repository Model*** will be right choice when we have business entities that comes from multiple datasource.