# how to configure the multiple user databases in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

For each user there will be different connection settings in global database in user table and on successful login of a particular user i will get his respective database settings such as database name,username,password but how do i configure that user database settings into laravel database.php file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One answer is given by @Abdulla Nilam on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

The solution to connecting your laravel application to multiple database can be found on this link. 
http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections
I hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the solution. but this above link is to configure the multiple database connection. but i want to configure or connect to that particular database of each user on the flow to do some database related operation.