# Laravel Querying model in a multi tenant/db

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am starting with a new multi-tenant applicaiton, i followed this as guide http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections.

**So in my model i have**

```
class Manufacturer extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'secondDB';
    ...
}
```

**I know i can query the second database like this:**

```
$users = DB::connection('secondDB')->select(...);
```

**But how do i query the model? This doesn't work:**

```
Manufacturer::create($attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (removing  Environment Configuration)

http://tutsnare.com/connect-multiple-databases-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

Hey here you can do like

```
    $Manufacturer = new Manufacturer;

    $Manufacturer->setConnection('secondDB');

    $result= $Manufacturer->find(1);

    return $result;
```

You can look at this [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel#)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
$manufacturer->setConnection('secondDB');

$this->create($attributes);
```

Hope this one help you.