# Laravel seed database from existing database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-seeding

i have now new structure of my database, but i need to import the old data in the new format. For that reason i want to use the Laravel seeder, but i need somehow to connect to the old database and make select queries and to tell the seeder how to put the data in the new database.

Is that possible ?

Comment: I think your best bet is to export your data from the old database with a tool such as phpMyAdmin, modify the data to fit your new database and then upload it.

Comment: by modifying do u mean in editor ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configure your laravel app to use two mysql connections ([How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)), one for the new database, the other for the old one.

*I'll fake it like `old` and `new`*.

In your seeds read from the old database and write into the new.

```php
$old_user = DB::connection('old')->table('users')->get();

foreach ($old_users as $user) {
     DB::connection('new')->table('users')->insert([
         'name'     => $user->name,
         'email'    => $user->email,
         'password' => $user->password,
         'old_id'   -> $user->id
         // ...
     ]);
}
```

Make sure to add messages while seeding like `$this->command->info('Users table seeded');` or even a progress bar (you can access command line methods) to know at which point of the import you are.

Comment: Thank you @phaberest, unfortunately i miss something. I have made a second connection (mysql_old) as in the example and put the name of it in the new DB:connection('mysql_old'). With all() it gives me Call to undefined method Query\Builder::all(). I have tried with select() and i put a print_r($old_users); and here comes the strange part. It prints me the whole MysqlConnection object, but in the config part the name is 'mysql_old', but the database is the wrong one from 'mysql' connection.

Comment: Make sure you don't reference any `.env` variable in your `config/database.php` as they have precedence over any other setting. You caught me...it has to be `get()` instead of `all()` :D

Answer (score 13):

Try: 
Examples:

```
php artisan iseed my_table
php artisan iseed my_table,another_table
```

Visit: https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

Comment: the problem with this package is the tables of whom we want to create a seeder we have to tell about it 


In my case I want to create a seeder for all the tables and this package fails to achieve that goal. 

If I'm missing something please advice

Answer (score 1):

Download package from 
Git repo : https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

then update below file src/Orangehill/Iseed/IseedCommand.php
Add below code at line number 75

```
// update package script
    if($this->argument('tables') === null){
        $tables = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
    }
```

and update getArguments method in same file with below code

```
array('tables', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'comma separated string of table names'),
```

and then run `php artisan iseed` so it will get all the tables from your existing db and start creating seeders for all tables