# How to create new table with different database connection in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

What i am doing is, want to create table in another database which is not set in .env file. and i want to do this on controller functionality. And I am using a eloquent model throughtout my project. How to create table with this scenario?

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the linked question that @szebasztian provided in the comment, take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-tables). You can specify what connection `Schema` will use to create the table when running a migration in this way:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

`foo` is the new connection you define in `config/database.php`.  I would personally still add the connection details (host, username, password, etc) to `.env` for that information.