# Execute multiple laravel alter table migration queries in one?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

Does anybody know if there is a way to execute multiple Laravel alter table migration queries in one query?

For example:

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('column 1');
    $table->integer('column 2');
});
```

This would create two ALTER table queries. Is there a way to make it do all in one query, other than writing SQL query.

Comment: I don't think this would be possible. I'm curious about why you want to do that though. Is there a performance benefit?

Comment: Actually yes, I just did the testing. I created table with 10 milion records. Alter in one query takes slightly more time than one of the separate alter queries.

Answer (score 4):

I realise this question is quite old now, but it wasn't answered.

I would say that the Laravel schema builder is more for convenience and cross platform compatibility, rather than for performance.

If you want to optimise `ALTER` queries, I would suggest using the `DB` facade and writing raw SQL.

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN a, DROP COLUMN a;');
});
```

Comment: How would that statement change if the table being altered wasn't under the default schema?

Comment: @AdrianLynch - look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel