# Multiple databases in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, multi-database

We are building a multi-tenant application. Through the admin interface, we will add new tenant as and when required. This application needs to work with 1+n database.

1 Main DB with about 5 tables. 
n DBs for each tenant that we create. The tenant specific database may reside on the separate db server altogether.

Question:

1. What is the best way to achieve this ?
2. Where do we store the the db connection information for each tenant ?
3. Sometime, we may have to fire join queries on tables in tenant and main db.
   How would this work?

Thanks in advance for reading and any possible solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend, so is the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#using-multiple-database-connections

```
config/database.php
```

And add a new connection for each database-connection you want to use.

To switch connections:

```
$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set the DB connection in `config/database.php` in connections part:

```
'connections' => [
    //Our primary DB
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    //Secondary DB
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB2_DATABASE', 'secondary'),
        'username' => env('DB2_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB2_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```

And for Model we can add

```
class User2 extends Model
{
   protected $connection = 'mysql2';
}
```

And in migration we can use connection method.

```php
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('table')
```

And if you use Eloquent ORM we can use `setConnection('mysql2')` on it.

```php
$user = new User2;
$user->setConnection('mysql2');
```

This answer based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. However, in case of our application, we will go on creating multiple tenants and for each tenant there will be a separate DB. 

Hence, we need a mechanism to store the DB connection information for each tenant.

Any inputs on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case a wont use multi-tenant
store child db configurations in main database
set child db params in middleware
use $connection = 'child' in needed models
join is not possible, because may be different servers, but huge part of relations is work propertly (not whereExists, withCount.. etc)

Hope it`s help