# Laravel : How to insert the result queried from MongoDB into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel

I have some data that saved in MongoDB,I want to transfer them to MySQL.

I use MongoDB PHP Library to do this,and I write a demo for test below:

MongoDB PHP Library docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php

TestController.php

```
   //insert some test data into mongodb
   public function insertMongodb()
    {
        $collection = (new \MongoDB\Client)->test->articles;

        $collection->insertMany([
            ['title' => 'hello', 'content' => 'hello...'],
            ['title' => 'foo', 'content' => 'foo...'],
            ['title' => 'bar', 'content' => 'bar...'],
        ]);
        dd('ok');
    }



    //query the data from mongodb and insert them into mysql
    public function queryAndInsertMysql()
    {
        $collection = (new \MongoDB\Client)->test->articles;

        $cursor = $collection->find();

        //how to write next?

    }
```

In mysql,there is a table `articles`,it has these fields:

```
id
title
content
```

I want to transfer the query result from mongodb into mysql table `articles`.

**Question:**
In the second function `queryAndInsertMysql()`,how to insert the result that queried form mongodb into mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are a little confused about how to insert records in Laravel. You are calling the `insertMany()` method on a Collection.

I would suggest setting up 2 database connections in your application, 1 for the MongoDB and 1 for the MySQL.

See this question and answer for help on creating multiple database connections in Laravel [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Then pull from one database and insert into another:

```
$articles = DB::connection('mongodb')->table('articles')->get();

DB::connection('mysql')->table('articles')->insert($articles);
```

If this is a one-off task it should possibly be part of a migration not a controller.

Comment: Thanks!There is another question when running the code,see my update.

Comment: You've edited your original question so it now includes my answer but with a new additional question. This is very confusing for future readers and StackOverflow advises against asking multiple questions in the same post. Consider moving this problem to a new question and keeping the original question and answer as a consistent pair.