# 2 Laravel projects on one DataBase

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to make 2 projects based on one database. Imagine a site like `airbnb.com`. I want one project to be for "managers of hotels" that will add their supply on the website, and the other site to be a powerful search by location, name, and so,so on based on the same DB. There is a way how to achieve it?
It will not cause problems after deploying ?

Comment: you can do this, go ahead.

Comment: First site for suppliers will interact with CRUD of app. The other app will be just a "search" from the first one's DB. 
Any recommendations, suggestions, probably issues? Thanks!

Comment: You will just end up with a project that has a dependency on another project. Are you ok with that? Then you're done.

Comment: Why two projects? The manager part is just a different view based on role to the same data? Do I miss anything?

Comment: That's the idea. I know that posting it all on one domen will be better, but... I didn't decide :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be fine given

- A table is maintained by one project only
- You never do php artisan migrate:fresh or other actions affecting the other projects´ tables.

Comment: First site for suppliers will interact with CRUD of app. The other app will be just a "search" from the first one's DB. 
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not really recommended, instead adopt 1 DB for 1 application. If your app needs to connect on external DB, you can connect multiple DB with one single app.

Please see here:

[multiple-database-connections-in-the-same-laravel-project](http://laraveldaily.com/multiple-database-connections-in-the-same-laravel-project/)

[use-multiple-database-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)