# Laravel Bridge registrations

Tags: php, laravel, trinitycore

I'm working on a trinitycore website, and want users to register on laravel,
The details should be saved in the website database but also in a seperate database on another host, with other creds. however laravel hashes passwords i guess.

so my guess would be before it gets hashed, hash it again in SHA and sending it to the other database?

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel version 5.6:
I think your first step is to go to app/Http/controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php and go to the method create, over there you have the $data variable. You could do whatever you want with the data from here. This is the point that the user is being saved to your default database before being hashed.Refer to here for using multiple databases: [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Comment: Yes, however where does it say which database its going to, i mean i ned to send the same data to two databases not one.

Comment: Do you intend to only store in that second db? Or you will use it to retrieve data inside this same application?