# laravel 5.6 use another server databases

Tags: php, database, laravel, connection, laravel-5.6

Am new in `laravel` I want to connect two `database` in my `laravel` project.

- 1st `database` in **same server**.
- 2nd `database` in **another server**.

This question already asked but that not relate my question.

**I tried this code:**

`.env`

**1st database connection**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thedaldb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**2nd database connection**

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=delivery_test
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=thedal
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=thedal
```

`app/config/database.php`

**2nd database connection**

```
'onlineorder' => [
            'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND'),
        ],
```

> I don't know what is added in 2nd database connection `DB_HOST_SECOND` ?

Comment: Have you tried this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel

Comment: @IftieaqMurshed: Yes i tried this only but i don't know what added in `DB_HOST_SECOND`

Comment: @IftieaqMurshed: How can i connect `another sever database`?

Comment: I think you need to update your config/database.php file according to the first answer of the link I posted before.

Comment: It the second database is on another server, you need to change the "host" to point to that server. We can't help you with that. We have no idea where that server is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You mean i want to add my hosting IP ?

Comment: I mean that you need to but the URL or IP to that database server. We don't know where it is. We also have no idea if that server even is open for remote connections.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay let me try URL or my hosting IP ..!