# Two database connection in one query in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, connection

I need to use INSERT INTO...SELECT but using two different database in Laravel. Database A is a local database. Database B is a remote database.

I need something like this :

```
INSERT INTO local.table1
SELECT * 
FROM remote.table1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=col1
```

Is there any way I could achieve this in laravel? Thanks!

Comment: u want to select rows from local and insert rows into remote database..am i right?

Comment: no, I want to select rows from remote and insert into local database @JigneshJoisar

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple database connections in Laravel. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel) post.

Then to utilise it :

```
<?php 

$selectQuery = \DB::connection('remote')
    ->table('table1')
    ->select('column1','column2','column3');

\DB::connection('local')->insert('INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3) ' . $selectQuery->toSql(), $selectQuery->getBindings());
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It seems selectQuery uses 'local' instead of 'remote'. Is it possible I need something else to make this work?

Comment: If its different servers altogether then you need to create a table with [federated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) engine.