# Multiple database laravel

Tags: laravel, show, laravel-blade, multi-database

How to show the value from other database in a view? i am using multi database. 
My Controller :

```
public function index()
    {

        $oil = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('oils')->select('oil_price')->get();

        $this->oil = [
            'oil_price' => $oil
        ];

        return view('home')->with('oil', $this->oil);
    }
```

This is my view :

```
 {{$oil['oil_price']}}
```

Output is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phA1H.png)

I want show only 10000.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Comment: Do want to show all the `oil_price` form databse or only the `first`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try this:

**Your Controller**

```
public function index()
    {

        $oil = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('oils')->select('oil_price')->get();



        return view('home',compact('oil'));
    }
```

**Your view like** :

```
@foreach($oil as $oildetails)

 {{$oildetails->oil_price}}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change the **$mySqlConnection, $tableName, $filedName**:

```
public function index()
{

    //to get all the value of oil_price

    $mySqlConnection = 'CONNECTION_NAME';
    $tableName = 'TABLE_NAME';
    $filedName = 'FILED_NAME';

    //to get all the oil_price(only) from the databse

     $controlVariableOne = DB::connection($mySqlConnection)->table($tableName)
                                            ->select($filedName)
                                            ->get();

                                            foreach ($controlVariableOne as $controlVariableOneKey => $controlVariableOneValue) 
                                            {
                                                $allcontrolVariableOneValues [] = $controlVariableOneValue->$filedName;

                                            }

        $controlVariableTwo = DB::connection($mySqlConnection)->table($tableName)
                                            ->select($filedName)
                                            ->first()->$filedName;



                        dd('All the Values From Databse ', $allcontrolVariableOneValues, 'First From Databse ',$controlVariableTwo);

        $viewShare = ['controlVariableOne','controlVariableTwo'];

        return view('home', compact($viewShare));
    }
```