# Migrate a laravel project with a single database to multiple bases

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I would have to make many modifications to be able to transfer my laravel project with a single database that has many query builders and eloquent to a project that supports more than one database?

I understand that once a new database is installed it is necessary to use:

```
connection('mysql2')
```

When consulting a database, do we tend to change the whole project with this sentence? specifying the connection in each place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Understand that you are asking basically how to change database.

For whole project:  you can edit mysql connection details in your .env file.

You can also use 2 databases with 1 project , you can learn how to do that from this question which has been already answered: [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

I am sorry if i didn't understand your question.
Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Not exactly, my question goes to how much code I would have to modify already in a project already created with a single database, so that my project supports multiple databases, Sorry for my not so good English

Comment: Yes for that you can visit the question i added the link of, in the answer above ^. The person who answered it has provided many different ways to switch between databases , from 1 line code each time to 5 - 10 line of code once.

Comment: I am glad you understand , if you have any problem understanding the code , let me know i will assist you. Have a nice day buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `$connection` property to your Eloquent models to specify the database connection there. This way you don't need to update your queries.

```
protected $connection = 'connection-name';
```

Comment: and in the case of all the consultations created with query builder

Comment: Jerodev's answer is also present in the answer i forwarded. He deserves an upvote. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

`Migration` with multiple connections

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('mysql-2')->create('user_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //........
    });
}

public function down()
{
  Schema::connection('mysql-2')->dropIfExists('user_details');
}
```

Handle Relationship with multiple database connections

`UserDetail.php` //mysql-2 (connection-2)

```
class UserDetail extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql-2';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->setConnection('mysql')
                    ->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`User.php` //mysql (connection-1) //default connection

```
class User extends Model
{
    //with default connection

    public function detail()
    {
        return $this->setConnection('mysql-2')
                    ->hasOne(UserDetail::class);
    }
}
```

You don't need to a specified connection in a controller for retrieving/delete/insert data