# Laravel one domain, multiple database detected by Session

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have read several posts/topics (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel), [this](https://medium.com/teknomuslim/how-to-run-laravel-using-multiple-database-connections-d7e8dcb7ed2a) and [this](https://laravel-tenancy.com/)) about the subject SaaS, Multi-Tenant, etc. and I reached the conclusion that most of them does not fit my requirements:

1. I don't need a multi-tenant as i'm only going to use the main-domain
2. I can't write in .env nor in database.config all my MySQL connections as they will all be dynamic (at least the name of the database)

**Workflow i need**:

1. The subscriptions (SaaS) contains the database name
2. Whenever the user login it is assigned to his session the database name
3. Run all the queries to the user database

Example:

```
- project_admin <- Main database 
--- subscriptions <- Table
------ id | db_name
------ 1  | project_child_one
------ 2  | project_child_two
--- users <- Table
------ id | subscription_id 
------ 1  | 1 
------ 2  | 2

- project_child_one <- Child database
--- customers <- table

- project_child_two <- Child database
--- customers <- table
```

- When the `user 1` login, the data retrieved from customers should be from database `project_child_one`.
- When the `user 2` login, the data retrieved from customers should be from database `project_child_two`.

I want the database name to be saved in the session so I don't need to always query the `project_admin` in order to know in which database the user should connect to. This is the easy part.

Comment: **Don’t** store database connection settings in a session. Instead, consider using middleware to dynamically set the connection based on the authenticated user if you must have multiple databases.

Comment: @MartinBean i'm not gonna store the connection settings in session, only the database name. I have not figure out yet how do i use a middleware with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to have a “tenant” database connection, then you can configure it on the fly in a middleware class:

```php
class ConfigureTenantConnection
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($user = $request->user()) {
            // Create a tenant database connection if there is an authenticated user
            config([
                'database.connections.tenant' => [
                    'driver' => 'mysql',
                    // I don’t know what column names you use, but…
                    'host' => $user->database_host,
                    'port' => $user->database_port,
                    'database' => $user->database_name,
                    'username' => $user->database_username,
                    'password' => $user->database_password,
                ],
            ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You can then use this `tenant` connection in database queries and models:

```php
abstract class TenantModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'tenant';
}
```

---

```php
class Widget extends TenantModel
{
    protected $table = 'widgets';
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, can you take a look at a related problem I'm facing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791809/laravel-request-validation-with-custom-tenant-connection-on-the-fly

Comment: @Linesofcode You’ve already accepted an answer. Not sure what you’re wanting me to add?

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure whether this is what you meant .
 But if you want db name to be dynamic you can easily do it in the laravel as follows . The connections part of config should be like above . However you can change the database credential at the controller in the runtime . 
    If we take the above example for the configuration then . You can do like this on the controller .

```
    $config= [
            'database'=>'Dynamic db name',
    ];
    Config::set("database.connections.mysql2",$config);
    DB::purge('mysql');
    DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql2');
```

And suppose you want to switch another db after transaction you can do like this

```
     $config= [
            'database'=>'Dynamic db name',
    ];
    Config::set("database.connections.mysql",$config);
    DB::purge('mysql2');
    DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql2');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: More information can be found [here](https://divinglaravel.com/understanding-how-laravel-configures-database-connections).

Comment: I don't want to do that in the controller. I need it to be in the model or inject somehow in a middleware.