# Laravel request validation with custom tenant connection on-the-fly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an SaaS application with multiple databases and the connection to the database is set on-the-fly according to the user logged in. [You can see my problem and solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908755/laravel-one-domain-multiple-database-detected-by-session) back when I was trying to figure out how to do it.

My problem now is using the `$request->validate` function with both `unique` and `exists` functions.

The documentation says that we can set a Custom Database Connection, by doing something like:

```
'email' => 'unique:connection.clients,email'
```

But this forces me to create my connections within the `config\database.php` file and that's something I don't want to do.

Currently, if I do:

```
$request->validate(['email' => 'required|unique:clients,email']);
```

I got an error saying:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mydb_admin.clients'

Which is correct, since my Admin database does not have the table `clients`. So how can I, with the system I have in place, use the `$request->validate` function with my child databases?

Comment: Can't you use `tenant.clients` since you are adding a `database.connections.tenant` in the middleware no?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes I can, it worked. Would you like to set it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this since you are already setting the `tenant` connection in your middleware:

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|unique:tenant.clients'
]);
```