# how to use Auth and Config together in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my project, I need to use multiple databases depending on each user where `users` table is in separate database.

First I get `users` database using `Auth->user()->db` and pass it to `Config::set()`. But, when I try to get data from the new database, `Laravel` tries to connect to the first one.

How can i fix it?
The `users` database is set in `env` file.

```
$db= Auth::user()->name;

Config::set('database.connections.sqlsrv', [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '1433',
    'database' => $db
]);

$query = DB::connection('sqlsrv');
$posts = $query->table('posts')->get();
```

Comment: check this first : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)