# How to use database connection from database of another system?

Tags: php, laravel, database-connection, laravel-5.8

I have and database of my project configured in another system. And I want to set connection details of another system.

I have tried to set database connection details of .env file which contain another system host, port, database name, username, and password.

```
DB_HOST=192.168.1.111
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel

Comment: yes @AdityaThakur has referred you to correct place, much more information than my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these things in you .env file and after that config/database.php

```
'mysqlRemote' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_REMOTE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB__REMOTE_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_REMOTE_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_REMOTE_USER', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_REMOTE_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

now you can use this connection like

```
 $data = DB::connection('mysqlRemote')->select( DB::raw('SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10') );
```