# Laravel 5.5 mysql driver error when using two databases

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I got a second database in my laravel project and i want to display the data in the second database, I didint migrate the second database because it have already tables and data. When i want to display the data it gets me an error of Unsupported driver [mysql2]. What is the problem of this? I already followed the instructions here [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Graph.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Charts;
use DB;

class Graph extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'ico_stages';
}
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HoQcNyCc5KEGw4yjqpBIdKzTC+yeDoOJcerVMEVx+fs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=adminpanel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=



DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=ricjac8_orocoin
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

config/database.php

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD','forge'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

GraphController

```
public function test(){
    $graph = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT * FROM ico_stages WHERE id = ?", [1]);
    dd($graph);
}
```

Comment: Do you have try to extends `Eloquent` on your model ?

Comment: yes sir

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: I mead `class Graph extends Eloquent`. Because your reference answer is extends `Eloquent` not Model.

Comment: no sir. where should i put that ?

Comment: If you write this, `$this->setConnection('mysql2');` on your model construct.

Comment: my model doest have a construct function sir

Comment: You can use this to check connection `$this->getConnection();`.

Comment: You can write construct by yourself.

Comment: i already did sir but it still get the same error.

Comment: I found you should modify this config `'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),` to `'driver'    => mysql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change `DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2` to `DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql`

Because in `config/database.php` file, that is the `driver` not the `connection name`

```
'mysql2' => [
        'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
```

Comment: Thanks sir it worked!!! I spend hours in finding the error. THANKS a lot

Comment: It worked for me too. I was doing the same mistake.