# Laravel: Copy models/rows from one connection to another

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to copy an eloquent model from one connection to another.

The way I have done this so far is as so:

```
$users = User::on('connection1')->where('tenant', 'foo')->get();
User::on('connection2')->insert($users->toArray());
```

This works most of the time. But there are cases where this does not work. For example:

- When the model has `$hidden` attribute
- When the `toArray` method for a model is overrided

What is a reliable way to simply copy over some rows to another connection?

Answer (score 1):

i think i have found a solution for $hidden attribute & overwriting toArray method

```
 $users = User::on('connection1')->where('tenant', 'foo')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
            $usersArray[] = $user->getAttributes();
        }
User::on('connection2')->insert($usersArray);
```

if you are using mySql i recommend using bulk insert:

https://www.geeksengine.com/database/data-manipulation/bulk-insert.php

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `setConection()` method on the eloquent model like so:

```
$users = User::on('connection1')->where('tenant', 'foo')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $user->setConnection('connection2');
   $user->save();
}
```

I found this in another stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Comment: This solution will fail if the user doesn't exist on the `connection2` before executing the `save` method

Comment: You can add `$user->exists = false;` before the `save()` to create a non-existent user