# How to select sub-query with left join inside using eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm very new to Laravel, how can I make this query in Laravel using Eloquent model:

```sql
SELECT
(
  SELECT departments.deptname FROM school.counts
  LEFT JOIN reference.departments
  ON counts.departmentcode = department.departmentcode
  WHERE counts.countid = a.countsid
) AS departmentDesc
FROM school.subjecthdr a
LEFT JOIN school.subjectdtls b
ON a.subjectid = b.subjectid;
```

I don't wish to use raw queries, is there any way? I still appreciate raw query suggestions if there's any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need some raw queries.

```php
$dept_desc = \DB::table('school.counts')
->leftjoin('reference.departments', 'counts.departmentcode', '=', 'departments.departmentcode')
->whereRaw('counts.countid = a.countsid')
->selectRaw('departments.deptname');


\DB::table('school.subjecthdr AS a')
->leftjoin('subjectdtls AS b', 'a.subjectid', '=', 'b.subjectid')
->selectRaw('(' . $dept_desc->toSql() . ') AS departmentDesc')
->get();
```

*PS: I think you `leftjoin subjectdtls b` but it seems you don't need it.*

And you are using not only one database, if you want to use `Eloquent\Builder`,
you need to do something like this:
[How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Comment: Thanks mate, It is just a chunk query. I will just improve this on actual. It is really a great help!