# Laravel - How to do DB Connection to Slave Database

Tags: database, laravel, connection, replication, slave

as the title above, I need to do connection to slave database (for some reason)...

But I cannot find how to do it?

.

Below is my database config:

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => env('DB_SLAVE', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_SLAVE_PORT', '3306'),
        'username'  => env('DB_SLAVE_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_SLAVE_PASSWORD', 'pwdforslave'),
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => env('DB_MASTER', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_MASTER_PORT', '3308'),
        'username'  => env('DB_MASTER_USERNAME', 'masteruser'),
        'password'  => env('DB_MASTER_PASSWORD', 'pwdformaster'),
    ],
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'amazingapp',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'aa_',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', 'InnoDB'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
],
```

.

To do connection with slave DB, currently what I'm thinking is `DB::connection('mysql.slave');`

But it is not working..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you mean create new database connection entry inside `database.php` and connect with statistic method through `DB::connection('mysql2')` ?

maybe you can check this link [Laravel Multiple Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

.

Can try this configuration

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => env('DB_SLAVE', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_SLAVE_PORT', '3306'),
        'username'  => env('DB_SLAVE_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_SLAVE_PASSWORD', 'pwdforslave'),
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => env('DB_MASTER', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_MASTER_PORT', '3308'),
        'username'  => env('DB_MASTER_USERNAME', 'masteruser'),
        'password'  => env('DB_MASTER_PASSWORD', 'pwdformaster'),
    ],
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'amazingapp',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'aa_',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', 'InnoDB'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
],  

'mysql_master' => [
    'host' => env('DB_MASTER', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_MASTER_PORT', '3308'),
    'username'  => env('DB_MASTER_USERNAME', 'masteruser'),
    'password'  => env('DB_MASTER_PASSWORD', 'pwdformaster'),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'amazingapp',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'aa_',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', 'InnoDB'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
],  

'mysql_slave' => [
    'host' => env('DB_SLAVE', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_SLAVE_PORT', '3306'),
    'username'  => env('DB_SLAVE_USERNAME', 'slaveuser'),
    'password'  => env('DB_SLAVE_PASSWORD', 'pwdforslave'),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'amazingapp',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'aa_',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', 'InnoDB'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
],
```

.

So, if want connect to slave, just use `DB::connection('mysql_slave');`

Comment: i thought there's an easier way without copy/paste the same configuration.... but if there's no easier way, then i think i will mark your answer as the CORRECT one...

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien There's no easier way than [copy/paste](https://i.imgur.com/uoRcizT.jpg). :P

Answer (score -1):

You can do multiple `DB` Connection on your `.env` without touching your `database.php`

This is how I connect my multiple DB connection

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=sample
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=123456


 DB_CONNECTION=mysql1
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=sample
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

and when you want to call it on your codes as stated by `protrafree`

Something like this

```
  DB::connection('mysql')
```

or

```
   DB::connection('mysql1')
```

Comment: wait...we can set duplicate variable in `.env` ??? i don't think so...