# Laravel 6 - 2nd Database configured in database.php but still received Database connection [] not configured

Tags: php, database, laravel, multiple-databases

I want to create a second database to act as a backup. I've been following [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847198/8782422) solution and other websites which leads to the same thing. I've added a new DB connection in .env and configured it in database.php, cleared out the cache using `php artisan config:cache`. When I try to migrate using `php artisan migrate --database=backup_literature_review_management`, it says InvalidArgumentException, Database connection [backup_literature_review_management] not configured.

### .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=literature_review_management
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_BACKUP=mysql
DB_HOST_BACKUP=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_BACKUP=3306
DB_DATABASE_BACKUP=backup_literature_review_management
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

### database.php

```
'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_BACKUP', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_BACKUP', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_BACKUP', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

    ],
```

### Cleared cache before migrating

`php artisan config:cache`

### Trying to migrate to 2nd DB

`php artisan migrate --database="backup_literature_review_management"`

### Error

InvalidArgumentException, Database connection [backup_literature_review_management] not configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the wrong connection. Use this:

```php
php artisan migrate --database="mysql2"
```

You can also define the connection inside the migration file like:

```php
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('table', function (Blueprint $table) {...
```

With this last command, you can ommit `--database="mysql2` in the migration command. I personally prefer to declare the connection inside the migration file.

Hope it helped!