# How to copy certain tables and data from Db A to Db B in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5.8, I have to copy certain tables and the data stored within each table, from the database A to the database B.

Then, the tables from Db A need to be removed.

Has anyone worked on something like this ?

Comment: Do you have access to mysql(or other) database via command line or even in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan

Following this issue : [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

You can declare 2 databases into Laravel Project, create into your command who select all data what you want DB A and insert to DB B.