# HasManyThrough multiple database

Tags: php, laravel

I've two databases.

wordpress: database1

mysql: database2

database1 has table wp_posts (Post.php model)

database2 has table news_tag(NewsTag.php model) and publishers(Publisher.php) model.

```
wp_posts has:
id
```

```
news_tag has: 
id
post_id 
publisher_id
```

```
publishers have:
id
```

I'm trying to access the publisher from the wp_posts. How can I achieve it?

In the Post.php model, I've tried something like:

```
    public function publisher() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
     Publisher::Class,
     NewsTag::Class,
     'post_id',
     'publisher_id',
     'id',
     'id',
     'id');

}
```

Maybe I'm not being able to access multiple databases in same model? 
I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]:
 Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_news.wp_publishers' doesn't exist
 (SQL: select `wp_publishers`.*, `wp_news_tags`.`post_id` as `laravel_through_key` 
from `wp_publishers` inner join `wp_news_tags` on `wp_news_tags`.`id` = 
`wp_publishers`.`publisher_id` where `wp_news_tags`.`post_id` in (?) and 
`wp_publishers`.`deleted_at` is null and `wp_news_tags`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Comment: did you define the two database connections?

Comment: @Makdous, there is no problem with the connection.

Comment: This needs more information to be answerable. Does the table `wp_publishers` exist on `db_news`?

Comment: I guess the question here is: is it possible to link two mysql databases? I know it only from ms sql server: if you would like to query two tables from two different databases at once you first have to link those two databases by configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection the two databases is correct as mentioned in the comments (if not you can see @Abdulla Nilam [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel) it describes how to set up multiple database connections),  then the only problem is your *table name* is not being picked up by Laravel.

Try to manually define it:

```
class Publisher extends Model
{
    /**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'wp_publishers';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `hasManyThrough` cross-databases, unless the credentials from one connection can access the other database.  This is because the underlying query for `hasManyThrough` contains a `JOIN` operation.

If you can access both databases through one connection, you can probably do it with a custom solution.  Either you'll want to extend `HasOneThrough` as a custom relationship, or if you're willing to be even riskier, you could override `newHasOneThrough()` in the model itself.

A better solution is to probably just define the relationships independently.  So you would have:

- WPPost `HasMany` NewsTag
- NewsTag `HasOne` Publisher

Then you can eager-load via `WPPost::with('newsTag.publisher')`.  So you still get the benefit of the relationship, it can work cross-database (because HasOne/HasMany loads relationships by doing separate queries by primary key), and it should only require 3 queries to fetch any number of posts.

The downside is that you can't add constraints on the query.  So you wouldn't be able to search for all posts with a given publisher via Laravel's built-in relationship queries.  You would need to add something like `public function findByPublisher(Publisher $publisher): Collection` to the WPPosts model.  Pseudocode:

```php
    public function findByPublisher(Publisher $publisher): Collection
    {
        $tagIds = NewsTag::where('publisher_id', $publisher->id)->select('post_id')->distinct()->pluck('post_id')->toArray();
        return self::whereIn('id', $tagIds)->get();
    }
```