# Connect to different DB's depending on authentication method with Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, authentication

Is it possible to connect to different DB's (both mysql) with Laravel depending on the authentication method of the user?

Example:

- User A : authentication method: web --> DB1
- User B : authentication method: API --> DB2

Comment: Yes, possible. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847198/4575350

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!