# Laravel multiple database connection dynamically after login

Tags: php, laravel, multi-database

Recently I'm working on a laravel which is a shop management system,  where every shop will have its own database. User have access database connection access from session after login. But I can't establish this system by own.

Answer (score 3):

For an application similar to this, I have a tenants database and table where I store the subdomains and connection data for each tenant.

Then, I built a Middleware like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Config;
use Closure;
use App\Models\Tenant;

class SubdomainSetup
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $subdomain = $request->server()['HTTP_HOST'];

        $tenant = Tenant::where('subdomain', $subdomain)->firstOrFail();

        config([
            'database.connections.mysql.tenantid' => $tenant->tenantid,
            'database.connections.mysql.host'     => $tenant->host,
            'database.connections.mysql.database' => $tenant->database,
            'database.connections.mysql.username' => $tenant->username,
            'database.connections.mysql.password' => $tenant->password,
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and add it to my global Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    .....
    \App\Http\Middleware\SubdomainSetup::class,
];
```

so every request goes through this setup first.  That way, you set up your connection transparently based on the subdomain name.

Easy, clean and secure.

Comment: It is not multi domain system.

Answer (score 1):

One way to change connection at runtime is to set the values via the config:

```
config(['database.connections.mysql_new_connection' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user_name'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
]]);
```

then you can specify a connection via the DB facade:

```
DB::connection('mysql_new_connection')->select('');
```