# Laravel - Specify database connection on the fly

Tags: laravel

I'm using 2 databases in my Laravel application. I have an SQLite DB which is local and a remote MySQL DB. Right now I need to switch `env` files to connect to each DB when I need to. My question is, is it possible to switch env files so the models which I'm using for both of the DB work on the corresponding DB.

This project is fairly new so if anyone knows a better way to handle this I'm all ears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Comment: No, I've already looked at this before creating a post. my question is how to use 1 model for 2 databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define several `connections` on your `config/database.php` file and access each connection via the `connection` method on the `DB` facade:

```
$sqliteUsers = DB::connection('sqlite')->select(...);

$mysqlUsers = DB::connection('mysql')->select(...);
```

Check ["Using Multiple Database Connections"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections) Section on Laravel docs for more info.

You may use `on` method on eloquent models:

```
use App\User;

$sqliteUsers = User::on('sqlite')->get()

$mysqlUsers = User::on('mysql')->get();
```

You may also specify a connection for an eloquent model statically:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'sqlite';
}
```

Check ["Database Connection"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connection) Section on Laravel docs for more info.

Comment: Can this be achieved with Eloquent models?

Comment: What about using 1 model for 2 databases? Is there a way to change the $connection while calling the model?

Comment: @Neavehni You may use `on` method, I updated my answer again.

Comment: This solves my problem. Where did you find this "on" thing? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.