# how to Run SQL insert Using Multiple Database Connections

Tags: laravel

this my code

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->insert('INSERT INTO pm_booking_service (id_booking, title, qty, amount) VALUES ('2','restaurant','1','27')' );
```

I don't know how to do insert Using Multiple Database Connections
but select is working fine

```
$bookings = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select * from pm_booking');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a string that starts with a single quote you need to escape any single quotes it contains otherwise they are interpreted as closing the string.

Use parameters to not need to quote the values manually:

```
DB::connection('mysql2')
    ->insert('INSERT INTO pm_booking_service (id_booking, title, qty, amount) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [2,'restaurant',1,27]);
```

An example of this can be found in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-insert-statement) as well

This can be rewritten in the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements) as :

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('pm_booking_service')
    ->insert([ 
        'id_booking' => 2,
        'title' => 'restaurant', 
        'qty' => 1,
        'amount' => 27
    ]);
```

[Update statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-update-statement) are also written similarly:

```
DB::update(
    'update pm_booking_service set qty = ? where id = ?',
    [100, 2]
);
```

This also can be written in the query builder as:

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('pm_booking_service')
    ->where('id', 2)
    ->update([ 'qty' => 100 ]);
```

Comment: it works thank you ,what about update can you give me an ex for update value () where id = id