# How can I access multiple databases in a single configuration in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

I have a multitenant application, below I have 2 connections defined, one is the default that is used by the application and the other is one that is used to access the central database while I am on the tenant connection.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'central_mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'hybrid_central',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Below is how I would normally access the central database from the tenant.

```
 $u = User::on('mysql')->where(['username' => $this->credentials['username']])->get()->first();
```

Is there a way I can call a specific database in eloquent and preform an operation on it?
e.g
If have two databases named **Aaron** and **Mike** is there a way I can call **Aaron** in eloquent?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel

Comment: Im actually trying to use just one connection to access other schemas in Maria DB .