# How to use two different database one from sql server and another from mysql server in same laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I am developing a laravel application. I connect my laravel application with a mysql database. But I need a table data that is in another server and that database is sql database is in IIS server.

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),





   'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=line
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I need help to use two databases from different server (one from mysql and another from sql) on my same laravel application.

Comment: this question already answered in page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel

Comment: @FiroozMeysami yes I found it but it was about two mysql database. But I want to use one mysql and one sql database.

Answer (score 1):

In your config/database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

// Add this (Connect sql server)
//TCP port 1433 is typically the port used by a default instance of SQL Server
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env(''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'X.X.X.X'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

Get your mysql table

```
$mysql = DB::connection('mysql')->table('xxx')->select('*')->get();
```

Get your sql server table

```
$sqlsrv= DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('xxx')->select('*')->get();
```