# How create model for multi database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project.
I have three databases. the first database is for the current project and I can use migrations.
I know how I can connect to it and use migrations.
Two other databases I should connect to it.
but I want to use `Model` instead of using the query.
for example:

in the second database, I have this table:

```
works
id - title
```

in the third database, I have this table:

```
logics
id - title
```

I want to use `Work::first()` or `Logic::get()` in current my Laravel project;

What can I do?

Comment: Would https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#database-connections help?

Comment: Why don't you use `protected $connection = 'DB_Connection';` in your model? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel/31847198#31847198

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have defined the 3 connections in `config/database.php`
if so then in each model you need also to define

```
protected $connection = 'yourConnection';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add new database connection in /config/database.php

For example (mysql connection):

```
'yourNewConnectionName' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('ADB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('ADB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('ADB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('ADB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('ADB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('ADB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Then in each model you need to define:

```
protected $connection = 'yourNewConnectionName';
```