# How use multiple database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use multiple database in my project. first databaseis postgresql and the second one is mysql.

this is my database config :

```
'mysql_second' => [
     'driver' => 'mysql',
     'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_SECOND'),
     'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
     'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
     'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
     'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
     'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
     'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_SECOND', ''),
     'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
     'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
     'prefix' => '',
     'prefix_indexes' => true,
     'strict' => true,
     'engine' => null,
     'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
      ],
```

in my controller, i try this to check the connection

```
try {
    $dbconnect = DB::connection()->getPDO();
    $dbname = DB::connection('mysql_second')->getDatabaseName();
    echo "Connected successfully to the database. Database name is :" . $dbname;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error in connecting to the database";
}
```

and the database was successfully connected. Then I try to get the data from database like this

```
$database = DB::connection('mysql_second');
$data = $database->select('SELECT * FROM data_sales_suspect');
echo $data;
```

and it return `500 Internal Server Error`

How can I get data from the second database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple databases in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Comment: why not check the logs to see what is causing the 500 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define as below:

Here it's config.php

```
'connections' => [

'second_db' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('SECOND_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('SECOND_DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('SECOND_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('SECOND_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('SECOND_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
],
```

],

Set Environment Variables Like this:

```
SECOND_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
SECOND_DB_PORT=3306
SECOND_DB_DATABASE=DEMO
SECOND_DB_USERNAME=root
SECOND_DB_PASSWORD=******
```

Now that you've configured the second database connection, you can use it in your application.

**use the DB::connection() method:**

```
$users = DB::connection('second_db')->table('users')->get();
```

Please make sure If you want to associate a model with a specific database connection, you can define the $connection property in the model class:

```
class DemoModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'second_db';
}
```

Comment: i've already define the connection in model but it is always return Internal Server Error


`use HasFactory;
    protected $connection = 'mysql_second';
    protected $table = 'data_sales_suspect';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_customer';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nm_customer'
    ];`

Comment: @MiftaKhussolikhin Can yo u turn on the error reporting and let me know which error laravel throwing.